# how to keep the uiimage in the original format

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiscrollview

Hello I've created a Class, this class allows the user to take a selfie and after that the user can select the filter that he wants, but the thing is, I'm able to take the photo, after that the original image appears at the top of the screen, but the buttons that has the same image are in different position I mean the photo in the button is flipped I and want to keep the image in the original position. Here's my code and I'll add an image of the screen, and you will see what's happening.

Thanks.
[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8y40.jpg)

```
import UIKit
import SVProgressHUD
var filteredImage: UIImage!
class SelectFilterViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var originalImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageToFilter: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    //var imageToShow = photo
    var CIFilterNames = [
        "CIPhotoEffectChrome",
        "CIPhotoEffectFade",
        "CIPhotoEffectInstant",
        "CIPhotoEffectNoir",
        "CIPhotoEffectProcess",
        "CIPhotoEffectTonal",
        "CIPhotoEffectTransfer",
        "CISepiaTone"
    ]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        originalImage.image = photo
        var xCoord: CGFloat = 5
        let yCoord: CGFloat = 5
        let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 80
        let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 80
        let gapBetweenButtons: CGFloat = 5
        var itemCount = 0

        for i in 0..<CIFilterNames.count {
            itemCount = i

            // Button properties
            let filterButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
            filterButton.frame = CGRect(x: xCoord, y: yCoord, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
            filterButton.tag = itemCount
            // filterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.filterButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            filterButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(filterButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
            filterButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6
            filterButton.clipsToBounds = true
            let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
            let coreImage = CIImage(image: originalImage.image!)
            let filter = CIFilter(name: "\(CIFilterNames[i])" )
            filter!.setDefaults()
            filter!.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            let filteredImageData = filter!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
            let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, from: filteredImageData.extent)

            let imageForButton = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef!)
            filterButton.setBackgroundImage(imageForButton, for: .normal)
            xCoord +=  buttonWidth + gapBetweenButtons
            scrollView.addSubview(filterButton)
        }

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: buttonWidth * CGFloat(itemCount+2), height: yCoord)

    }

    func filterButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        let button = sender as UIButton

        imageToFilter.image = button.backgroundImage(for: UIControlState.normal)
    }

    func createTheAlertForEmptyImage() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "xxxxx", message: "xxxxx", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "xxxxx", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func clickSaveButton(_ sender: Any) {


        if self.imageToFilter.image == nil {
            createTheAlertForEmptyImage()
        } else {
            filteredImage = self.imageToFilter.image!
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToFilter.image!, nil, nil, nil)

        }





        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "xxxx", message: "xxxxx", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "xxxxx", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
            let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CaptureViewController") as! CaptureViewController
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    let finalImage = filteredImage
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

   }
```

Comment: A few possibilities. First, I'll assume you already know that a `CIImage` has an origin in the *lower left* instead of the *upper left*. But have you checked out the `UIImage.imageOrientation`? Here's a good repo to help you with this: https://github.com/FlexMonkey/CIImage-UIImage-Orientation-Fix

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try with your advice, and if it works I'll let you know.